# Selecting all the row having any values equal to the target row

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have table `user_product`, which have different rows as `user` and column as the `product` that they have bought. Suppose we have a target user with `user_id` 3. So what I want to do is to get all the users who bought any `product` that the target user have bought. That is the rows which have any column values equal to target column value.

```
user_id | product_one | product_two | product_three | product_four |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1       |   1         | 1           |   0           |1             |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2       |   0         | 1           |   0           |0             |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
3       |   0         | 0           |   1           |1             |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
4       |   0         | 0           |   0           |0             |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
5       |   0         | 1           |   1           |1             |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

here if our target row is 3, than we should return row 3( by default because its target row), row 5( because of product three and product four) and row 1( because of product four)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated it.

Comment: You haven't asked a question. By the way: this looks like a very bad database design. Will you never add or delete products? Because if you wanted to do this, then products should not be columns but mere data, for which you'd want a product table and a separate bridge table consisting of user_id + product_id.

Comment: If you have more than 4 products like around 10 more new product will your table have new columns till product_fourteen?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes I understand it is not good practice but I need to make just a quick web app for demo will change later because of short span on time I'm sticking with it.

Comment: @James But I am making this app considering that the number of product don't change.

Comment: Then answer given by @tim will works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try phrasing this using an exists query:

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM products p1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM products p2
              WHERE (p1.product_one = 1 AND p2.product_one = 1 OR
                     p1.product_two = 1 AND p2.product_two = 1 OR
                     p1.product_three = 1 AND p2.product_three = 1 OR
                     p1.product_four = 1 AND p2.product_four = 1) AND
                    p2.user_id = 3);
```

[image]

### Demo

But note that if you were to change/normalize your table design, you might have a much more tractable problem.  Consider storing your data this way:

```
user_id | product_id
1       | 1
1       | 2
1       | 4
2       | 2
3       | 3
3       | 4
5       | 2
5       | 3
```

Now we can phrase the problem more simply:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM products t
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT p2.user_id FROM products p1 INNER JOIN products p2
                  ON p1.product_id = p2.product_id WHERE p1.user_id = 3);
```

### Demo

Comment: @AbhishekPatel I gave you alternative way of storing your data (and a query) which is probably a better design choice moving forward, assuming you are in a position to do that.

Comment: I will switch to the later one. Thank you so much for your help.